# ProcessBuilder opens wrong folder while trying to open file from read only folder

Tags: java, file, directory, readonly, processbuilder

I'm trying to open a file saved in a read only folder using `ProcessBuilder`, but it's opening "My Document" folder instead.

```
 ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", "/select,"
 +fileName); p.start();
```

While using the same file path with Runtime.getRuntime.exec() method works fine.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select," + fileName);
```

Since, `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` should be avoided, I need a fix for the `ProcessBuilder` problem.

Comment: What's the value of the string `fileName`? Maybe it has spaces which is causing one to work and the other to fail.

Comment: Downvoting your question until you edit it to provide the necessary information.